# Generating jest test suites as separate files instead of single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

I need to run similar tests on a bunch of different files, and I do so using a single test suite file.

**Example:**

```js
for (const configName in defaults) {
  const config = defaults[configName];
  const onMobile = testMobile.includes(configName);
  const onDesktop = testDesktop.includes(configName);
  describe(`${configName}`, () => {
    const tests = (isDesktop:boolean) => {
      let defaultConfig: AttnConfig<MultiPageCreativeConfig>;
      function freshRender() {
        cleanup();
        return render(
          <TestWrapper isDesktop={isDesktop} layout={defaultConfig.creativeConfig.base.fields.layout.layout}>
            <ConfigCtx.Provider value={defaultConfig}>
              <App />
            </ConfigCtx.Provider>
          </TestWrapper>,
          {
            container: document.documentElement
          }
        );
      }

      beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        mockedUseWaitForPageLoad.mockReturnValue(false);
        mockedUseResponsiveLayout.mockReturnValue([isDesktop]);
        defaultConfig = attnTestConfigWrapper(config);
      });
      afterEach(cleanup);

      for (let page = 0; page < config.pages.length ;page++) {
        describe(`Page ${page + 1}`, () => {
          beforeEach(() => {
            defaultConfig.overrides.currentPageIndex = page;
            freshRender();
          });
          itPassesVisualRegressionTests(!isDesktop);
        });
      }
    }
    if (onMobile) tests(false);
    if (onDesktop) tests(true);
  })
}
```

This way however, does not take advantage of multithreading. Since I will only ever be running these tests alone, it takes considerably longer (about two-three times longer) than writing a separate test file for each config.

As much as I would like to write the tests in individual files, this causes a lot of extra work if I need to refactor something (I've already had to change these files several times).

**Is there a way generate test suites for jest to run in parallel or at least break out test logic into a shared utility function?**

Comment: did you checkout out the concurrency method? you can do `it.concurrent(...)`, which i assume its what you have on `itPassesVisualRegressionTests`

Comment: @Dus Its weird I can't find any documentation on that option :/
But yeah that solves my performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added concurrency to my tests:

```
export function itPassesVisualRegressionTests(mobile = false, debug = false) {
  const itPassesVisualRegressionTestsOn = (browser: string) => {
      it.concurrent(`has no visual regressions on ${mobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'} ${browser}`, async () => {
      await sleep(400); // wait for animations
      const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
      // Pixel 3a (adjusted for high dpi) and generic 1080p desktop
      // Note we use a high-res phone due to desktop browsers having a minimum width
      const viewport = mobile
        ? { width: 540, height: 1110 }
        : { width: 1080, height: 720 };
      const image = await fetchSnapshot(html, { browser, debug, viewport });
      expect(image).toBeTruthy();
      expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot();
    });
  };
  itPassesVisualRegressionTestsOn('chrome');
  itPassesVisualRegressionTestsOn('firefox');
  itPassesVisualRegressionTestsOn('operablink');
}
```

**Edit:** I tested this and this causes problems when speaking to the snapshot server. If I could create locks around `fetchSnapshot` I should be fine...